# Extra blank <a></a> showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I go to my menu to sign in it works perfectly fine and there is nothing extra but when I am signed in there is an extra blank  at the top. How can I fix this?

**Server Side html.erb**

```
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <a><%= link_to('My Account', edit_user_registration_path) %>
      <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to('Log in', new_user_session_path) %>
      <%= link_to('Sign up', new_user_registration_path) %></a>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

**Client Side Html (Logged In)**

```
<a></a>
<a href="/users/edit">My Account</a>
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Sign out</a>
```

**What it looks like**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have to write explicit tag

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
# => <a href="/">Home</a>
```

**So**

```
<%= link_to('My Account', edit_user_registration_path %>
# => <a href="/users/edit">My Account </a>
```

To remove the extra href tag one, just remove the tag and its closing from your code. and it will render the view correctly.

[More Information about link_to helper method](https://mixandgo.com/learn/how-to-use-link_to-in-rails)

Comment: This did not work for me. I got a syntax error instead of displaying anything.

Comment: don't copy past.
I just explained what link_to metho does.
only remove <a> and </a> from your code and it will work fine.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you so much!